# SearchPanel in Odoo 14 change DEFAULT_LIMIT

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Odoo 14 SearchPanel view have DEFAULT_LIMIT = 200, how can i change this limit? I needed to add this value to settings and change it if i need to.

Looks like i need to extends JS ActionModel view, but i dont understand how.

```
const ActionModel = require("web/static/src/js/views/action_model.js");
const DEFAULT_LIMIT = 500;
class SearchPanelModelExtensionChangeLimit extends ActionModel.Extension {
    prepareState() {
        Object.assign(this.state, { sections: new Map() });
        this._createSectionsFromArch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the default limit of of the SearchPanel view in Odoo 14:

1. In Odoo backend, go to  "Settings" App.
2. In the top menu, click on "Technical" tab and select "Parameters"
3. In the search bar, search for web.search_panel.default_limit.
4. Click on the result, and in the form view, change the value of this field to the wished limit for the SearchPanel view...